# GA Custom Dimension Error: ga("gtm1.set", "dimension1", undefined)

Tags: google-analytics

This is the code implemented by my developer for defining Custom  Dimension. I have created new variables in GTM and added custom dimension to Universal Analytics tag.

In datalayer the variable values are showing correctly but in Pageview tag, it shows as Undefined. How to resolve this?

```
       <script>
        var dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        var categoryName = 'GST News and Announcements';
        var parentCategory = 'gst';
        var trackParams = {};
        if (parentCategory) {
            trackParams['blogCategory'] = parentCategory;
            trackParams['blogSubcategory'] = categoryName;
        } else {
            trackParams['blogCategory'] = categoryName;
        }
        dataLayer.push(trackParams);
    </script>
```

Comment: We would need to see the configuration of your pageview tag and your GTM variable to see what's wrong.

Comment: Datalayer Variable Config: http://www.clipular.com/c/4531830811525120.png?k=_1No_0nZMM2Im8x8O_WpBuocLG8

Tag Config: 
http://www.clipular.com/c/4662245949964288.png?k=j4Ewo3zTykyTqMhsl3N67TS0v-Y

Is these okay?